# Fail to dump my database with mysqldump, on MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a production database on MySQL, with windows installer.

It had installed MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47 and MySQL.

Now ,I want to launch mysqldump to get a backup of my production database.
mysqldump is in MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47 directory right.

So i launch this dos command :

```
/mysqldump -udu -pdu mydatabase_prod > d:/test.sql

Version of mysql : mysqldump --version => 5.5.16.
```

And ... starting .. FAILED
I've got this ugly error :

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)

Can I get an earlier mysqldump.exe ?

Why is mysqldump older than MySQL workbench version ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mysql-server installed you will find all neat tools in the bin of that installation-folder:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

Here you will find the "mysqldump.exe" which will produce its workbench-independend *.sql-dump. 
You have to set the dumper in the workbench: edit -> preferences -> administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Your server comes with a mysqldump tool too. Use this instead to get your dump done, if you want to do it manually. You could however let Workbench do the dump for you (see Admin section).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here (it works for Windows too) : [MySQL server 5.6 + MySQL WorkBench 5.2.47 = dump error under OSX](http://www.renderwarrior.com/2013/02/mysql-server-5-6-mysql-workbench-5-2-47-dump-error-under-osx-mysqldump-couldnt-execute-set-option-sql_quote_show_create1/#comment-428)